# why tailing "-c" a DB log file doesn't work and gives "tail: cannot open input"

Tags: bash, tail

I am making a bash script to grep the last n bytes of my DB log file to search for errors

```
tail -c 271 prod/BOPRD2/orasrc12/diag/rdbms/boprd2/BOPRD2/trace/alert_"$ORACLE_SID".log
```

doesn't work and give this error:

```
tail: cannot open input
```

Comment: Does it work without the -c? Is your file a normal file or is it some kind of pipe/socket?

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include the exact command you ran, and the exact output it gives?

Comment: @nneonneo yes it works without the "-c" option. and it is a normal file

Comment: @thatotherguy the command is written between parentheses. and below it is the output it gives.

Comment: @Yuki When I run the command `tail -c n "full path to the log file"`, I get the output `tail: invalid number of bytes: ‘n’`. Please edit your post and include the exact command you run, and the exact output it gives. Please avoid modifying or paraphrasing the command, and copy-paste it instead. If you don't feel like you can share the command, please edit it *before* and not *after* you run it. See [Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)

Comment: @thatotherguy i've edited the post with the exact command i run

Comment: Sounds like Solaris `tail`. Chances are you can use `tail -271c yourfile.log` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/tail -c 271 yourfile.log`

Answer (score 0):

The correct `tail` command is:

```
tail -n 271 prod/BOPRD2/orasrc12/diag/rdbms/boprd2/BOPRD2/trace/alert_"$ORACLE_SID".log
```

Replace `-c` to `-n`